# How do you detect why Document.Open freezes when opening an RTF?

Tags: vba, ms-word, rtf

Context:

- VBA macro embedded in an MS-Word document.
- Old code running for 15+ years under Word 2003 without issue.
- Upgraded to Word 2019
- Existing/Previous RTFs open without issue
- Upgraded server from "Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard" to "Windows Server 2016 Datacenter"
- The troublesome RTF is a copy of another RTF that works without issue.  No edits were made.

I make the call

```
   On Error GoTo docerr
      Set gobjDoc = Documents.Open(gstrTEMPLATE_PATH + gstrTEMPLATE_NAME)
   docerr:
      WriteLog ("ERROR Documents.Open: " & Str(err.Number) & "-" & err.Description)
```

where `gstrTEMPLATE_PATH + gstrTEMPLATE_NAME` provides a fully qualified path.  I've logged this value it continues to be accurate.

**For the new/copied RTF, the interpreter gets to the Documents.Open statement and never returns.  No error is thrown.**

Does anyone know why is doesn't return?  Is there a way to force a return?

I added the parameter `OpenAndRepair:=True` with no effect.

FYI: This is my first question on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

The [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article states the following:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

> Microsoft strongly recommends that developers find alternatives to Automation of Office if they need to develop server-side solutions. Because of the limitations to Office's design, changes to Office configuration are not enough to resolve all issues. Microsoft strongly recommends a number of alternatives that do not require Office to be installed server-side, and that can perform most common tasks more efficiently and more quickly than Automation. Before you involve Office as a server-side component in your project, consider alternatives.

For example, the Open XML file formats are a public standard. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.

Also you may conside using any third-party components designed for the server-side execution, especially, for RTF files.

Comment: Eugene, thank you for your response.  First, I agree with you about unattended, non-interactive client applications for Office.  This is an inherited application; therefore, I must live with it.  Second, the application is only acting on documents local to the same server; therefore, it does not have the issues of a server-side acting on a client side object.

Can you help me with why the Documents.Open method doesn't return and is there a way to force a return?

Comment: Who runs the code? Who opens a document with VBA macros enabled? A user?

Comment: Not a user.  A ColdFusion application running on the server.

Comment: This is the case - unattended, non-interactive client applications for Office.

Comment: Yes.  Can you help?

Comment: I'd suggest another way of implementing your task.

Comment: My employer doesn't support redesigning an old application.  I'd like to.  A different way to implement my task is essentially what I'm looking for.  Are the alternate ways to open a document?

Comment: You can use the open XML sdk or third-party components designed for the server-side execution.

Comment: Moving to Open XML SDK or another third-party solution sounds like a huge change the company won't support.  Can you help me with the Documents.open issue specifically?